# CListCtrl class override and OnTimer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

I'm not sure if I'm doing something undocumented. I created my own class derived from [CListCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) and then overrode the OnTimer handler in it:

```
void CListCtrl2::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    switch(nIDEvent)
    {
    case MY_TIMER_ID:
        {
            //Do my processing
            doMyProcessing();
        }
        break;

    default:
        {
            //Default
            CListCtrl::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

But what seems strange to me is that this OnTimer() routine is called with timer IDs that are not mine. For instance, just from a quick debugger checkpoint research it turns out that my `default` handler is called with `nIDEvent` set to `45` and `43`.

Are there some timer IDs that are reserved that I should avoid using myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `CListCtrl` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) we see this text:

> Also see:
>
> - [Knowledge Base article Q200054](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200054): PRB: OnTimer() Is Not Called Repeatedly for a List Control

And from that article, some pertinent excerpts:

> If you call the SetTimer function to send periodic WM_TIMER messages
>   to a list control, you may find that the WM_TIMER message handler (the
>   OnTimer function) for a list control is called only twice.
>
> ....
>
> The list control uses the timer for editing labels, and for scrolling.
>   When you handle the timer message, if the timer ID is your own timer,
>   don't call the default handler (CListCtrl::OnTimer).

So, this confirms what you observe. The list control uses the timer. I can find no documentation for the specific IDs that are used. I guess that Microsoft would not wish to commit to documenting the specific IDs that were used. They would regard the control's implementation as private and would wish to retain the option of using more timer IDs in future versions. But as IInspectable points out, they could have done that by reserving a range of IDs.

My recommendation is to regard the list control's timer as out of bounds, and reserved for use by the control. For your derived class, use a different timer. Create a message only window and use it to receive timer events. You can [subclass `CWnd` to achieve this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7969/How-to-make-a-Message-Only-Window).

Comment: I don't see, how not documenting the timer IDs is to be expected. The reserved range is part of the **public** interface as it does affect the implementation of a derived class. Specifying a range (similar to `WM_MOUSEFIRST`/`WM_MOUSELAST`) does not imply that the implementation is committed to use specific IDs for specific timers. It merely offers the implementation the option to choose from a valid range of IDs. And allows for a client to implement a reliable solution.

Comment: @IInspectable Fair point. I meant that I would expect MS not to commit to only using specific ones. But certainly reserving a range would be a reasonable thing to do. I would certainly expect them to at least document that the control uses the timer. I've tried to clean up that text.

Comment: After your edit, I'd put it even stronger: Documenting the range of used timer IDs is **mandatory** to allow implementation of a reliable specialization. Given the behavior of the `SetTimer` API, you have to provide a unique identifier. Even if the system assigns an ID for you, your initial `nIDEvent` must not collide with an ID already in use - else it replaces that timer, instead of creating a new one. So using timers in a `CListCtrl`-implementation is not possible, unless one chooses the needlessly tedious solution outlined in your final paragraph.

Comment: @IInspectable Perhaps MS did not expect anyone to subclass this control. Perhaps they just got it wrong. However, it is what it is. Given that the IDs are not documented, I don't see much alternative to the tedious solution of my final paragraph.

Comment: I may have been wrong with respect to the [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx) API. Passing `0` as the `nIDEvent` parameter (i.e. an invalid ID) will create a timer and return a system assigned ID, that can be stored and use to update and kill this timer. Assuming `CListCtrl` does the same, there are no collisions. This could be a possible solution as well. (Although I find it difficult to read the observed behavior with respect to ID assignment into the documentation for `SetTimer`.)

Comment: @IInspectable: Thank you both. I just tried doing `UINT nTimerID = SetTimer(0, 100, NULL);` but `nTimerID` is returned as always 1. So I don't think it's a timer ID, it's probably just a boolean. Another thought -- is there a way to enumerate existing timer IDs assigned to a window handle?

Comment: @c00000fd I observed the same: Regardless of how many times you call `SetTimer` with a 0 value for `nIDEvent`, it always returns `1`. I do not know of a way to enumerate existing timers, either. This leaves pretty much just a single option, the one that David outlined in the final paragraph.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks. What seems to have worked is to call `UINT nTimerID = ::SetTimer(NULL, NULL, 100, TimerProc);` or to specify 0 for `hWnd`. In that case the timer ID returned is unique, but that leaves a new issue of _marshalling_ `TimerProc` calls and tying them up with my window. In either case, the message window or this method, is not the easiest two-lines-of-code solution. My only observed bonus of going with a `TimerProc` implementation is that it seems to be generally faster than working with `WM_TIMER` notifications.

Comment: @c00000fd: Using a `TimerProc` may indeed be an option. This solution requires that your control implementation provides a static callback function, and a mapping of timer IDs to control instances (e.g. `std::map<UINT_PTR,MyCListCtrl*>`), also as a static class member. The static callback then uses this mapping to call into a specific control.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, that's exactly what I did. Although you don't need a static class member since you have `MyCListCtrl*` in your mapping. You can use it to emulate OnTimer() class method.